# Visual Studio regular expression replace

Tags: c++

I'm sorry if this questions have been asked before, but could not find an appropriate answer here.
I need a little help with Visual Studio regular expressions to modify source code.
I have source code that loads textures from files. I have lots of line like these.

```
D3DXCreateTextureFromFileA(pDevice , chFileName , &pTexture) ;
D3DXCreateTextureFromFileA(pDevice , pAttrib->Value() , &pd3dTexture) ;
```

I need to define a constant and based on that to load textures from a custom format.
I want this

```
   D3DXCreateTextureFromFileA(pDevice , chFileName , &pTexture) ;
```

to become this

```
 #ifdef LOAD_TEXTURES_FROM_CF

    CreateTextureFromResourceFile((pDevice , chFileName , &pTexture) ;

 #else

    D3DXCreateTextureFromFileA(pDevice , chFileName , &pTexture) ;

 #endif
```

How can I achieve this with Visual Studio regular expressions ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you want the macro solution? It works well in your case

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for regular expression replaces (I would even advice against doing so). Instead of duplicating your new code, just create another macro:

```
#ifdef LOAD_TEXTURES_FROM_CF
#define CreateTextureFromFile(a, b, c) CreateTextureFromResourceFile((a), (b), (c))
#else
#define CreateTextureFromFile(a, b, c) D3DXCreateTextureFromFileA((a), (b), (c))
#endif
```

Then just replace all previous occurances of `D3DXCreateTextureFromFileA` with `CreateTextureFromFile` and you should be fine.

Comment: Just to add: I'd actually think about using a tiny wrapper function instead of static code/a macro. That way you could even toggle loading at runtime, not just compile time.

Comment: Thanks for both of you. I will use a macro as you proposed.
Just out of curiosity - how a regex solution will look like ?